# fetching data from phpmyadmin using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which has the following columns date(date format),time_id(integer),location(varchar),status(number)
and I do the following query

```
$time=1;
$cur_date=date("Y-m-d");
$location=1;
$sql="select status from final where location = $location AND date='".$cur_date."' AND time_id=$time";
$query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
$stat=$row['status'];
echo $stat;
```

`$location`,`$cur_date`,`$time show` correct value on echo.But the query results NULL.I have checked database and according to it query should return a row.I think I have done mistake in writing where clause but cant figure it out. Thanks in advance

EDIT changing $location to '$location' in sql query did the job Thanx :)

Comment: `$location`,`$cur_date`,`$time` from where you getting these value ? please add the output of these variables so we can help u.

Comment: done as you can see I have defined them explicitly in code

Comment: You have spaces around your date (between `'` and `"`). Since they are in quotes, they are part of the matched value.

Comment: removed spaces still no use

Comment: What does `var_dump($sql);` yield?

Comment: Ah wait, try `'$location'` instead of `$location`.

Comment: Try proper quotes in sql query  $sql="select status from final where location = '".$location."' AND `date`='".$cur_date."' AND time_id = '".$time."'";

Comment: var_dump yields  string(92) "select status from final where location = Noida Sector 1 AND date='2015-06-24' AND time_id=1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to proper quoted your query. because your location is string and it must be in single quote `location = '".$location."'`

```
$sql="select status from final where location = '".$location."' AND date='".$cur_date."' AND time_id = '".$time."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space from `' ".$cur_date." '` single quotes.
Then the query will become

```
$sql="select status from final where location = $location AND date='".$cur_date."' AND time_id=$time";
```

Also you are getting the value of status variable in $stat and printing $status which is no where defined.

```
$stat=$row['status'];
echo $status;
```

This is wrong.

Comment: I already removed spaces and laso renamed variable status still no use